# How to make a search for an object with Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to build a small app with Flask. I must create a class and object. I want to make a function to search for the object, but I can't find how to do.

For now, it works well to search through the db.txt, but it gives back only one line and not the whole object. It would be needed to find the whole to be able to delete it.

How can I do that?

My class:

```
class Books:
    #properties
    def __init__(self, title, author, genre, comment):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.genre = genre
        self.comment = comment

    #methods
    #write info book
    def write_info_book(title, author, genre, comment):     
    
        file = open("booksdb.txt", "a")
        file.write("Title: " +title +"\n")
        file.write("\t" + "Author: " + author + "\n")
        file.write("\t"+ "Genre: " + genre + "\n")
        file.write("\t"+ "Your comment: " + comment + "\n")
        file.write("---" + "\n")
        file.close()

        return title + author + genre +comment
```

My route:

```
@app.route("/search")
def search_book():
    query = flask.request.args.get("q") 
    html_page = get_html("books")
    books = get_books()
    result = ""
    for book in books:
        if book.lower().find(query.lower()) != -1:
            result += "<p>" + book + "</p>"  
    if result == "":
        result+= "<p>" + "No result found" + "</p"
            
    return html_page.replace("$$BOOKS$$", result)
```

The route works well with the db.txt, but there should be a way to get the whole book object, no?

The route to save works well too

```
@app.route("/save")
def button_save():
    #pour chaque nouveau livre, écrire book +1
    title = flask.request.args.get("a")
    author= flask.request.args.get("n")
    genre = flask.request.args.get("g")
    comment = flask.request.args.get("c")
    books = Books.write_info_book(title, author, genre, comment)
    html_page = get_html("save")
    return html_page.replace("$$SAVE$$", books)
```

I can't use anything else like SQLAlchemy, or JSON

The get_books function

```
def get_books():
    booksdb = open("booksdb.txt")
    content = booksdb.read()
    booksdb.close()
    books = content.split("\n")
    if books == [""]:
        books = [elem.replace("", "You didn't add any book yet!") for elem in books]
    return books
```

Comment: Since you didn't show us the `get_books` function, we have no idea what you're searching through.  If `get_books` returns a list of objects, then you have what you need.  If `get_books` just returns a list of strings (like titles), then no, you don't have the information you need.

Comment: Oh.. sorry! I edited to add the function. But from what you say, it seems it would not be possible except if I rewrite everything, but I don't know where to start. I should rethink all, probably

Comment: What are you expecting here?  You never create any `Books` objects, so how can you possibly fetch the object?  You're just storing all of the lines as strings.   You're storing each line as a separate entry in the `books` list, but since you're storing each bit of information on a separate line, the bits for a single book are not associated with each other.  Yes, you have a fairly big rewrite.

Comment: I thought that in the line in the route /save `books = Books.write_info_book(title, author, genre, comment)`, it created the object book... When I tried to print the book, it gave me `<__main__.Books object at 0x7f8825b25fd0>`  from what i deducted that they are "somewhere", but i don't know where... And I obviously don't understand how to make the link between the obects and the fact I must write on a .txt file.  Beginner hoping to learn...

Comment: No on both counts.  `Books.write_info_book` does not create any objects, nor is it an object method.  You're calling it as a static class method; it writes a file and returns a string.  The fact that there's no "self" should tell you you've designed this wrong.  And `get_books` never mentions `Books` at all.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank your for your answers and explanations! I rewrote and I found how to do, I understood better. It seems it is doing what i expected.(and what is asked for the project).I think I am on the good way, now. (I found how to save correctly, still searching in the .txt file, but it seems to be ok, I will see by working on it)Should i post how i correct it?

Comment: Sure, that will help people coming by later.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I rewrote after the explanations, and it works as i wanted to save, creating an book object and writing in the .txt file.
Still have to find how to look for the book through his id

```
class Book:
    
    #properties
    def __init__(self, title, author, genre, comment, ):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.genre = genre
        self.comment = comment
        self.identity = id(self) #I tried that to work on the the search part, still don't get it yet

    #methods

    #write info book in db.txt
    def write_info_book(self, file):   
    
        file = open("booksdb.txt", "a")
        file.write("Title: " +self.title +"\n")
        file.write("\t" + "Author: " + self.author + "\n")
        file.write("\t"+ "Genre: " + self.genre + "\n")
        file.write("\t"+ "Your comment: " + self.comment + "\n")
        file.write("---" + "\n")
        file.close()
```

The @route to save the data:

```
@app.route("/save")
def button_save():
    title = flask.request.args.get("a")
    author= flask.request.args.get("n")
    genre = flask.request.args.get("g")
    comment = flask.request.args.get("c")
    book = Book(title = title, author = author, genre = genre, comment = comment)
    book.write_info_book(file= "booksdb.txt")
    
    html_page = get_html("save")
    return html_page.replace("$$SAVE$$", title +"\t" + author +"\t" + genre +"\t"+ comment)
```